# Database connection with PDO and Singleton class

Tags: php, pdo, singleton

I'm trying to establish a database connection with PDO and a Singleton class but I'm having trouble fetching data from the database.

I've been reading up on this but I'm still not sure how to call the Singelton class in my database file from another file and get the results printed out.
The error I'm getting right now is `Fatal error: Call to undefined function query()` in my db.php file, which is the last function in my database file. However I believe the function is defined.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my database (db.php) connection file:

```
<?php
class Database 
{
    private $_db;
    static $_instance;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mvcuser', 'root', '');
        $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        return query($this->_db,$sql);
    }

}
```

And here is the code in my index.php file:

```
<?php
    require_once 'model/db.php';

    $db = Database::getInstance();

    $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `if`, it doesn't make sense... Do: `$result = $db->query(...)`...

Comment: Ok! But I´m still getting the same error:(

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, yes the `if` does make sense!

Comment: What does not make sense is call `query` two times, that's what I meant...

Comment: So should I write: if ($result = $db) {} instead?

Comment: why do you want a singleton? Why don't you use raw PDO instance? Got any problem with it?

Comment: It´s an assignment and we´re suppose to have a Singleton class and PDO with the database connection, for learning purpose:) If you have any idea what I´m doing wrong please let me know. I don´t quite understand how to call the query from my index file... @YourCommonSense

Comment: you've been told twice already. get rid of `if () {` line and corresponding closing brace

Comment: and write previous line as $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');

Comment: No one person said to get rid of the if and then I was told not to get rid of it:/ I tried to get rid of the if but it didn´t work either... I´m getting the error undefined variable query, but is it not defined this way: $db->query('SELECT * FROM users'); ??? If I write this instead: $query = "SELECT * FROM users"; I´m getting the error: Array to string conversion... @YourCommonSense

Comment: in what line you get this error?

Comment: Thank you!!! It´s solved finally and the $query is defined:) I seem to complicate it sometime! I need to write: echo $row['username']; and it works. But I don´t quite understand why I can´t just echo out the hole $row? That´s when I get the Array to string conversion error... @YourCommonSense

Comment: because it's array. Can you wear whole wardobe, can't you? No, you can wear only one dress at a time. Same with echoing arrays

Comment: Ok I understand:) I thought I had made a variable that was able to print the hole row out with one word... Thanks for your help! @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of your `Database::query` method doesn't make sense. It looks like you're calling some PHP function `query` (which doesn't exist) and thus you get the error.
I think you might want to change the method's definition to:

```
public function query($sql) {
    return $this->_db->query($sql);
}
```

**Update:** and in your `index.php`

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM users';

if ($result = $db->query($statement)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it but it the gives me  Notice: Undefined variable: query in the index file. And also Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' .

Comment: Am I calling it correctly from my index file or do I need to change it as well?

Comment: You are currently doing `if ($result = $db->query($query)) {` but I can't see the variable $query defined somewhere

Comment: But isn´t it defined in the function in my database file? Otherwise I´m not sure what to define it to? My problem is I´m not sure how to connect the database file and my index file and collect the data:( I really appreciate the help! @ilpaijin

Comment: @GeekGirl: no, the variable `$query` isn't defined anywhere. See my update answer - there I replace `$query` with `$statement`.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it already with some of your help! This is the correct solution! Thanks again:)@Havelock

Answer (score 6):

I know this questing is a little old, but for anyone who found it from Google if you don’t want to create a wrapper method for every single PDO method, you can use this inside your singleton class.

```
public function __call ( $method, $args ) {
    if ( is_callable(array($this->_db, $method)) ) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_db, $method), $args);
    }
    else {
        throw new BadMethodCallException('Undefined method Database::' . $method);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `$db->query($statement)` or any other PDO method without having to define it inside your singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought about this question. I make different way to connect database. Also it's included form. it's like this.

**PHP**

```
class try_connect
{
    function connect($s_name,$db_name,$user,$pass)
    {
        $this->s_name = $s_name;
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$s_name;dbname=$db_name","$user","$pass");
            if ($db) {
                echo $db->query("select database()")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
            }else {
                echo "fail";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $get_server_name = $_POST["server_name"];
    $get_db_name = $_POST["database_name"];
    $get_user = $_POST["user"];
    $get_pass = $_POST["password"];
    $connect = new try_connect();
    $connect->connect($get_server_name,$get_db_name,$get_user,$get_pass);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="server_name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="database_name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="user"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Coding really nice. I love it. :)